# Gradle left-shift operator(<<) vs doLast behaviour difference

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

Quick question, with the leftShift being deprecated from the 5+versions of Gradle switching over to doLast I noticed a change in the behaviour of how the code works now with doLast.

Here, I have a very simple build.gradle as below:

```
def commonThingToDo = { task ->
    println "Running ${task.name}"
}

task CommonTask << commonThingToDo

task CommonTask_doLast {
    doLast {
            commonThingToDo
    }
}
```

Running gradle  from the command line yields the below results. I was under the impression that we can now use the left-shift operator (<<) as a synonym for the doLast method but the output in each case seems to be different even though the build was successful.

I am a bit confused and I would really appreciate if someone can explain what I am doing wrong.

```
    $ gradle commonTask

    > Task :CommonTask
    Running CommonTask

    BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 1s
    1 actionable task: 1 executed


    $ gradle CommonTask_doLast
    > Task :CommonTask_doLast

    BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 1s
    1 actionable task: 1 executed
```

Many Thanks,
Shankar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Switch to using `doLast` as you used `<<`:

```
task CommonTask_doLast {
    doLast commonThingToDo
}
```

`commonThingToDo` is already the right argument to `doLast`, it was wrapped within another Closure in your sample.